# Set value in nested object

Tags: javascript

I try to set a value into nested array by a key.

My Object looks like

```
var Obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: value,
  }
}
```

I try to set key1 by `key1.key2` like

```
const name = `key1.key2`

Obj[name] = value
```

I knew I need to do it like `Obj['key1']['key2']` but I get only a `string` which looks like `key1.key2`

Comment: Is it `key1` and `key2`, or `key` and `key1`?

Comment: Sorry I fixed. It is `key1` and `key2`. @WillisBlackburn

Comment: Are you open to / able to use a library here? There are a number of toolbelt libraries that will make this operation ridiculously easy (Ramda, lodash).

Comment: @tex Yes I can also use a library

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you don't mind using a library, [Ramda](https://ramdajs.com/docs/) and [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15) offer helper functions that make this sort of operation very simple

With Ramda (slightly more verbose than lodash for this specific operation, but I prefer Ramda to lodash):

```js
const Obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: 1,
  }
}

const name = `key1.key2`

console.log(
  R.assocPath(name.split('.'), 2, Obj)
)
// --> { key1: { key2: 2 } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.26.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
```

With lodash:

```js
const Obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: 1,
  }
}

const name = `key1.key2`

console.log(
  _.set(Obj, name, 2)
)
// --> { key1: { key2: 2 } }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```js
function setValue(obj, keyString, value){
 var keys = keyString.split(".");
 var tempObj = Obj;
 for(var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++){
  if(i == keys.length - 1){
   tempObj[keys[i]] = value;
   return true;
  }
  
  if(!(keys[i] in tempObj)) return false;
  
  tempObj = tempObj[keys[i]];
 }
}

var Obj = {
  key1: {
    key2: "value",
  }
}

if(setValue(Obj, "key1.key2", "new value")){
 console.log(Obj);
}
```

The setValue function recognizes when an invalid keyString is provided and returns false if that's the case so you don't run into any trouble. If iverything goes smoothly, it returns true.

Comment: I know this works, but I get only a `string` like `"key1.key2"` and can not do it like this, because of the `string`.

Answer (score 0):

Update: I think I now understand that you have a string with the value `'key1.key2'` and you want to use that to index `Obj`.

If that's what you want to do, first split the string into a list of keys, then evaluate each in series.

```
let keys = key.split('.')
let answer = keys.reduce((a, k) => a[k], Obj)
```

Update 2: If you want to set, then what you want to is find the object identified by the second-to-last key in your string, then use the last key to set value on that object.

```
let keys = key.split('.')
let target = keys.slice(0, keys.length - 1).reduce((a, k) => a[k], Obj)
target[keys[keys.length -1]] = value
```

Previous answer:  I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do here, so let's take it step by step.

First, the easy part. If you have some object `Obj`, then indexing it with a key gets or sets the value for that key. So this:

```
let Obj = {}
Obj['key1.key2'] = value
```

produces an object that looks like this:

```
{
    key1.key2: value
}
```

That's not what you want. You want an object that has one key, `key1`, and you want the value of that key to be another object with a key `key2`, and you want the value of `key2` to be `value`.

```
let Obj = {}                   // an object...
Obj['key1'] = {}               // that has key1, which is an object...
Obj['key1']['key2'] = value    // that has key2, which is value
```

To retrieve the value just use the same syntax as in the second line.

```
Obj['key1']['key2']
```

The key point (bad pun, sorry) is that there are two objects involved; one is `Obj` and the other is `Obj['key1']`.

Comment: I try to build a function which gets a `string` as key where can I set in a nested object a value by key like `key1.key2` which is splited by a dot, but it should also work If I only set a single key.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it like so:

```
function getVal(obj, key, val) {
  const keys = key.split('.');
  let pre = obj;

  for(let i = 0; i < keys.length - 1; i++) {
    pre = pre[keys[i]];
  }

  pre[keys.length] = val;

  return pre;
}

console.log(getVal({key1: {key2: 1}}, 'key1.key2', 2));
```

Comment: It should be `pre = pre[keys[i]]`. Or use `reduce` and don't worry about bugs like that.

Comment: yea. I always prefer reduce but decided to do it with better known syntax to better explain the thoughts behind the solution.